# Doctrine 3: one-to-one Unidirectional relationship doesn't return all fields

Tags: orm, doctrine

I have 2 Entities: **Thesis** and **DoList**.

Every DoList belongs to 0 or 1 Thesis. So we have a unidirectional one-to-one relationship from DoList to Thesis. Here is Thesis:

```
class Thesis
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @var int
     */
    protected int $thesisID;
```

and DoList:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Thesis")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="thesisID", referencedColumnName="thesisID", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $thesisID;
```

Of course i cut down the classes to show only the part that matters.

As far as my understanding is going. @ORM\JoinColumn should join the tables DoList and Thesis on
DoList.thesisID and Thesis.thesisID.

**I have no problem persisting thesisID in this relationship** but i can't **retrieve the value of thesisID when selecting all values from DoList** it just always is null.

Edit:

The column names have to be thesisID on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that i was not joining the tables when using the query builder.
I thought that when doing a query and selecting all rows from a table with query builder doctrine reads the relationship that i specified on the model and does the join query automatically.

***NOTE: DOCTRINE DOES NOT AUTOMATICALLY JOIN TABLES WHEN YOU SPECIFY THAT OPTION ON YOUR MODEL. YOU NEED TO DO THE JOIN FUNCTIONALLITY ON QUERYBUILDER.***

```
$qb->select(['u', 'c'])
            ->from('ThesisNET\Models\DoList', 'u')
            ->join('u.thesisID', 'c')
            ->where('u.instructor = ?1')
            ->setParameter('1', $username);
```

**this is how it eventually worked. (i just added the join option.)**